# Create dynamic CSS style from string with Angular items

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

When using dynamic class with property "Style". Including for example `item.Style="color: red"`

it is working fine.
But Visual Studio code throws error `} expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)` or similar.
Result is correct but Designer does not work:
[image: Result]

The label-result is 'red' in my case but how to avoid the syntax errors?

[image]

Error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'color: #DFFDD00;'`

[image: error on ngStyle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngStyle needs key + value as **object**. In that case a dictionary is needed. Try my style string to dictionary parser.

You can use it like default css and use all known basic CSS- Syntax.

**Example for item.Style**

```
background-color:blue;font-size: 22px;color:red;
```

**Angular**

```
<div [ngStyle]="setStyle(item.Style)">Hello World</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
private setStyle(value: string): unknown {
    console.log(value);
    if (value == "") return null;
    //Example: value = "background-color:blue";
    var properties = value.split(";");
    var keyValuePairs = {};
    properties.forEach(o => {
      var key = String(o.split(":")[0]).trim();
      var value = String(o.split(":")[1]).trim();
      if (key.length > 0) {
        keyValuePairs[key] = value;
      }
    })
    console.log("keyValuePairs: " + JSON.stringify(keyValuePairs));
    return keyValuePairs;
  }
```

**Result**

[image: result for stlye]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: You can use *pipe* and `attr.style` binding for this
(Which would also scale well through your entire app):

1. Create a *pipe* as sanitizer

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

2. Register the *pipe* within your module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SafePipe],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Use it everywhere...

`app.component.html`

```html
<p [attr.style]="key.Style | safe:'style'">{{key.Style}}</p>
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
export class AppComponent {
  key = {Style: "background-color:blue;font-size: 22px;color:red;"};
}
```

Result:

[image]

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-iodcgy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

References:

1. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer
2. https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b
3. https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes

---

The value for the `[ngStyle]` must be *key-value pairs* or an expression that returns *key-value pairs*.
You can use both `style` and `[ngStyle]` respectively. Angular would then merge them, e.g.:

```js
key = {Style: { 'font-size': '18px' }}
```

```html
<p style="color: red" [ngStyle]="key.Style"></p>
```

result:

```html
<p style="color: red; font-size: 18px;"></p>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-jd2g2t?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Error when using ```style={{myItem.Style}}``` = Syntax error on design. Error when using ```[ngStyle]="myItem.Style"``` = ```Cannot find a differ supporting object color: #D0D000;```

Comment: Perhaps I just dont understand. I set ```[ngStyle]="key.Style"``` and the value to ```{Style: { 'color: #D0D000; font-size': '18px' }}``` and it does not change any style.

Comment: @Nasenbaer Check this demo. I meant this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-jd2g2t?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Btw, the value you provided looks incorrect. It should be `{Style: { 'color': '#D0D000', 'font-size': '18px' }}` instead. This part `{ 'color': '#D0D000', 'font-size': '18px' }` must follow the JavaScript key-value object convention.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Problem is, that I can not read/write this solution as string in any database. The solution with the typescript parser method allows to not explain anything about ngModel because the string is default css, can be written and readback in database.

Comment: @Nasenbaer Okay, now I get it. It wasn't obvious at first what you were really trying to achieve. Sadly, I don't like the proposed solution, as it is not scalable.
I have updated my answer accordingly. Feel free to take a look at it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
[ngStyle]="'color: #000000; ' + key.Style"
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response. In that case the error is on runtime: ```ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'color: #D00000;'```